# Popup Scroll C++

Tags: c++

How do I add a Scroll Bar inside the popup window in C++?

I mention that my popup is created with WS_POPUP and it has a LTEX, CONTROL (with a check box and a ok button) and I want the text inside the popup to be scrolled, and the check box and the button to stay in the same place.

Is it possible to add a scrollbar to a LTEXT?

Thank you!

I tried to add the WS_VSCROLL after the DIALOGEX in the style area. The scroll bar shows on the popup but it doesn't work.

Comment: The `LTEXT` is for simple text. use in place `EDIT` which as more capabilities like multiline, scroll bars, ...